# ViewdidLoad called every time

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Why every time I change UIViewController embed in UINavigationController using show push in storyboard ViewDidLoad is called?

It hasn't to be called only once or I have to check programmatically if it is already loaded?

Another relative question:

In the following best practices found here in StackOverflow that user are talking about init method, but if my ViewController are loaded by storyboard where I have to initialise my properties?

Best practices

Remember not to do view controller initialisation in viewDidLoad. This is a common mistake. For stuff that should only happen once when the view controller is loaded, do it in one of the controller's init methods.

Comment: ViewDidLoad is calling when you push using segue because when ever segue execute it creates new object of the destination viewController and push it to navigation stack that's why viewDidLoad is beign called every time

Comment: @C_X And why even init method are called every time?

Comment: Because every time its creating new instance,

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called first time when the viewController's view is loaded, (either by accessing the view controller's view  or by presenting a view controller via  modal presentation or via a push presentation).  Once the view controller is loaded, viewDidLoad will not get called again.  If you want to use init method, you need to use `initWithCoder` for the things that are from storyboard.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called the first time the view controller's `view` is loaded. This can happen for many reasons some time after the view controller is initialized. Not just when it is presented.

Comment: Even I mentioned the same. Doesn't is sound like it ? I meant to say, what ever may be the presentation style, viewDidLoad gets called only when VC is loaded.

Comment: You seem to be saying that `viewDidLoad` is only called when the view controller is presented. I'm saying that isn't true. `viewDidLoad` can be called even if you never present the view controller. It's called when the `view` is loaded. The view will be loaded simply by accessing the `view` property.

Comment: So every time I push a new UIViewController a new istance of them are created?

Comment: You can create an instance of your ViewController and viewDidLoad is never called if you do not present the view controller or access the view property. Also, you cannot do all initializations like add subviews in init() because the view is not created yet.

Comment: but i has to be called only once. Apple says about Viewdidload: This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.                 So why every time is called?

Comment: Yes it is. How can you say that view did load is called multiple times in your case ?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewdidload")
    }

Comment: Yes that is correct. You are loading the view controller by pushing it. There is nohitng wrong.

Comment: you push 10 times, view did load gets called 10 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101614/discussion-between-sarita-and-mr-t).

Comment: @Mr.T You said *"you push 10 times, view did load gets called 10 times."*. That's only true if you create a new instance of the view controller each time. If you were to reuse the same instance over and over, `viewDidLoad` would only be called once.

Comment: isn't it true that when the VC is popped out (when u press back button), the old instance is removed from memory and when you again pushed, new instance is created and the VC is loaded again ?

Comment: @Mr.T It depends. In code at least, I can create a view controller and hold onto the instance. I can push and pop that same view controller instance all day. Or can create one, push it, pop it, discard it. Repeat. The latter is more typical but not a requirement. The key here is that there will be at most one call to `viewDidLoad` per `init...` of a view controller. But neither the `init...` or `viewDidLoad` is necessarily tied to how many time the view controller is displayed. They are independent.

Comment: Pushing up a SecondViewController emend in UINavigationController that is the result: